# Keep current node open and collapse other nodes in GetOrgChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, orgchart

I'm using [GetOrgChart](http://www.getorgchart.com) for creating organization chart.

Everything is running smooth and fine but, It doesn't allow you to collapse other nodes and keep current node open.

Please look into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzkj2tqc/18/) example, I fetched from there demos.

There is one method `expandOrCollapse` listed in their [documentation](http://www.getorgchart.com/Documentation) but, no detailed explanation on how it works.

I just wanted to know is this even possible in GetOrgChart component.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expand method.

Here is the signature of the method expand(node, callback)

- node – is the node object, if you know the id of the node that you want to expand the node object is orgchart.nodes[“expandToThisId”]
- callback – the orgchart will be expanded to the specified node with animation, the callback method will be called when the animation complete

And example:

```js
        var orgchart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("people"),{  
          expandToLevel: 2,
            scale: 0.5,
            dataSource: [
                { id: 1, parentId: null, Name: "1"},
                { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "2"},
                { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "3"},
                { id: 4, parentId: 2, Name: "4"},
                { id: 5, parentId: 2, Name: "5"},
                { id: 6, parentId: 3, Name: "6"},
                { id: 7, parentId: 3, Name: "7"},
                { id: 8, parentId: 5, Name: "8"},
                { id: 9, parentId: 5, Name: "9"}]
        });
        
        orgchart.expand(orgchart.nodes["5"]);
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
#people {width: 100%;height: 100%; }
```

```html
<link href="http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.js"></script>
<div id="people"></div>
```

Comment: Muse: Can you please explain how the `expand` method will collapse corresponding nodes and keep the clicked element expanded? In your example also when I clicked on node 3, node 2 didn't collapsed, node 2 also remained open. Thanks.